# How do I use SQLAlchemy to reflect Snowflake tables in one database and insert data into a different Snowflake database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's the goal raw SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO "db2"."schema2"."table" ("col1", "col2") 
SELECT "db1"."schema1"."tablea"."column1", 
       "db1"."schema1"."tableb"."column1"
FROM "db1"."schema1"."tablea" JOIN "db1"."schema1"."tableb" 
ON 
"db1"."schema1"."tablea"."join_col" = "db1"."schema1"."tableb"."join_col";
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy Core to reflect the tables. This is simple enough but the issue is I'm unable to reflect them in a fully qualified way.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, text
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, insert


engine = create_engine(URL(
    account="my_account",
    user="my_username",
    password="my_password",
    warehouse="my_warehouse",
    role="my_role",
)
)
metadata = MetaData()

with engine.begin() as cnxn:
    cnxn.execute(text("USE DATABASE db1;"))

tablea = Table("tablea", metadata, autoload_with=engine, schema="schema1")
tableb = Table("tableb", metadata, autoload_with=engine, schema="schema1")


with engine.begin() as cnxn:
    cnxn.execute(text("USE DATABASE db2;"))

table = Table("table", metadata, autoload_with=engine, schema="schema2")


sql = select(tablea.c.column1, tableb.c.column1)
sql = sql.select_from(tablea.join(tableb, tablea.c.join_col == tableb.c.join_col))

insert_stmnt = insert(table).from_select([c.name for c in table.c]), sql)

with engine.begin() as cnxn:
    cnxn.execute(insert_stmnt)
```

The problem is the `insert` statement fails because I have three tables and two different databases. I think the easy answer is when reflecting the tables they need to be fully qualified. Is that possible? If so, how? I've been trying all different combinations of `table_name` and `schema` in the reflection trying to include the database but have been completely striking out.

The only thing I've been able to do is print the insert statement and then manually add the databases to each table in the resulting string. Then, run the string. This completely defeats the purpose of SQLAlchemy IMO.

`python_full_version = "3.9.6"`
`sqlalchemy = "1.4.45"`
`snowflake-sqlalchemy = "1.4.4"`